# Twitter API twython: Post a tweet with a different account

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I can post a Tweet with simple code:

```
tweeter = twython.Twython("Consumer_Key", "Consumer_Secret",
                          "Acess_Token","Acess_Token_Secret")
tweeter.update_status(status="I am so excited for the new Interchange Map!")
```

The problem is, the tweet will be posted on my profile.
My Question is, can i post a tweet on a different account, but with my Keys and Tokens? Something like this:

```
tweeter = twython.Twython("Consumer_Key", "Consumer_Secret",
                          "Acess_Token","Acess_Token_Secret")
account = tweeter.login("username", "passwort")
account.update_status(status="I am so excited for the new Interchange Map!")
```

Comment: Keys and tokens are tied to a particular account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: consumer_key and consumer_secret are about the app. As Colin said, access_token and access_token_secret are about the user. So this is your "login/pwd". The number at the beginning of the access_token is the user's twitter id concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys and tokens are tied to a particular account, so you can't do this.